# node-sqlite3 db file is way too big

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I am relatively new to node.js and haven't been used english for quite long time. Sorry for inarticulate in expressing my thoughts in advance.

I am currently scraping bitcoin data from bitmex websocket using node-sqlite3.
It has been around 10 days and i got 3,746,416 rows take up 162MB of space.
Space is not problem as I added 640gb hdd on to my raspberry pi.

But 3.7 million rows is just way too big to even read from my windows pc application. (DB Browser for SQ LITE)

So I googled 'how to make separate db file on daily basis' something like that. But to no avail.

How to make this happen? is make a separate db file on daily basis even a good idea? If not, What is the better solution to this?

Comment: Please clarify: you say "space is no problem", then you say "3.7 million rows is too big".

Comment: I mean 162 megabyte of space is not a problem because I have physical hard drive of 640 gigabyte capacity. But problem is 3.7 million rows of data takes too long to read and analyse.

Comment: What kind of analysis are you doing? If it's in select queries, do you have appropriate indexes to speed things up?

Comment: Well, 3-4 million rows is not usually considered a BIG database. If you are talking about fetching for user display/browsing, then you need to use paging.

Comment: @Shawn Mostly I look up the data when price spike or falling down fast. I open windows db browser program(DB Browser for SQ LITE) trying to locate data from here to there, copy it past on txt file and open it on matlab and plot chart.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Well yeah. 3 million to someone is trivial, I understand. But for what I do it is. I hope it be just different file like 042719.db and 042819.db something like that so that I can open it and locate data just bit faster and manage entire db file more conveniently. that's all.

Comment: You should be automating that sort of thing instead of trying to do it manually.

Comment: @Shawn oh. okay. I will try that. Few more code to select certain rows and plot on browser. okay i got it. thanks. And Do you think making separate db file on each day is good idea? 10 day equals 3.7 million data points, think about years worth of data.. and managing that into one file is ... you know.

Comment: The database can handle the data, and can split it up easily and effectively. If you break it out into separate files, joining it back up for any reason will be real pain in the neck.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield So if I let the data to stack over a several year on a single file, if I select several thousand rows programmatically then there wouldn't be a performance issue? All I have to worry about is making this process by node.js not in windows application?

Comment: No, that's exactly the sort of thing databases are made for. And yeah, use whatever language is easiest for your platform.